# Cancel Drag & Selection event

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, dom-events, selection, drag

I'm using this function that I found in Chrome Resources Files (chrome://resources/js/util.js)  and is working well on Google Chrome.

```
    /**
     * Disables text selection and dragging.
     */
    function disableTextSelectAndDrag() {
      // Disable text selection.
      document.onselectstart = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }

      // Disable dragging.
      document.ondragstart = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
```

I want to cancel this events in Internet Explorer 8 but this doesn't work on it.

How can I cancel this events in IE8 ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/**
 * Disables text selection and dragging on IE8 and below.
 */
function disableTextSelectAndDragIE8() {
  // Disable text selection.
  document.body.onselectstart = function() {
      return false;
  }

  // Disable dragging.
  document.body.ondragstart = function() {
      return false;
  }
}
```